# Mongoose: how to populate inside an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, populate

i am using an express server to return db data and my schema is currently set up like so:

```
const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    isVisible: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    description: { type: String },
    shortDescription: { type: String },
    image: { type: String },
    labels: { type: Array, default: [] },
    category: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Category",
      required: false,
    },
    rating: { type: Number },
    numReviews: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    reviews: [reviewSchema],
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
```

and I try to populate it like so to get the user id and user's name inputted:

```
 const product = await Product.findById(req.params.id).populate(
      "review.user name id"
    )
    if (product) {
      res.send(product)
```

but I get the error;

```
If you are populating a virtual, you must set the localField and foreignField options
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The fieldname seems to be `reviews`, so wouldn't you need to populate `reviews.user`?

Comment: Wow, That was pretty stupid of me, Sorry for wasting your time! but thanks :)